# When to run git tag in GitHub and Jenkins?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I want to build Deploy Jenkins pipeline with Github.

This is my deploy flow:

- Clone the repo
- Run `npm i`
- Run `npm build -- --prod`
- Run docker build (from the dist - the framework isn't matter)
- Push the docker image to aws repo.
- Run `aws ecs update-service` to update the service on the cluster (aws shutdown the container and creates a new one).

How to handle `git tag`? when to run this command? after the clone step? or in my local computer and GitHub will trigger the Jenkins pipeline when tag hook happens?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with tags?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can merely be an opinion since there is no right or wrong.

In some cases you want to tag only if everything was completed (deployed) successfully. In other cases you want to tag every try (Jenkins build).

The actual question you have to answer is (and @jonrsharpe already mentioned this in a comment): What is the purpose of a `tag` in your project? What do you do with those `tags`?

In my iOS projects I usually just create a tag when a new build was actually deployed. If the Jenkins job failed before that I don't bother tagging.